# How to pass ajax event to client side callback in primefaces?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 10.0.0, and I am working with a data table that allows reordering of rows. I am trying to pass the reorder event in the client side callback when any reordering happens.

`<p:ajax event="reorderRows" listener="#{bean.doSomething}" oncomplete=#{dothis(passTheReorderEvent)} />`

Comment: `oncomplete` is JavaScript, not an action. What exactly do you want? This might be an XY question.

Comment: I want to be able to pass the reorderEvent to dothis() which is a js function. Sorry, if it was not clear.

Comment: That much was clear. The question is, why do you want to do that.

Comment: (Regular or lazy load) data table has already integrated mechanism for sorting data in column(s). Why not use that?